# Laravel - Storing a shopping cart has Multiple Data to the Database

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, session, laravel-5

I've created this online shopping cart, if a buyer buys with one checkout item, works well, but there is a problem when the buyer is shopping with multiple items, not working properly.

I need help, so that the items from the shopping cart can be put all into the database. My problem is inserting multiple products from the shopping cart into the database as individual rows. Can anyone help?

I want this because the items that have been purchased can be reviewed by the buyer who bought the item. so i can get "product_id".

Table: **orders**

Columns:

```
id int(10) UN AI PK
user_id int(11) 
product_id int(11) 
item_name text 
payment varchar(255) 
courier varchar(255) 
note text 
quantity int(11) 
total int(11) 
status int(11)
```

**OrderController.php**

```
public function NewOrder(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'payment' => 'required',
        'courier' => 'required',
    ]);
    $cart = Session::get('cart');
    $total = 0;
    foreach ($cart as $data) {
        $total_harga = $data['harga'] * $data['qty'];
        $qty = $data['qty'];
    }
    $quantity = $qty + 0;

    $new = new Orders();
    $new->user_id = Auth::user()->id;
    $new->product_id = $data['id'];
    $new->item_name = $data['item_name'];
    $new->payment = $request['payment'];
    $new->courier = $request['courier'];
    $new->note = $request['note'];
    $new->quantity = $quantity;
    $new->total = $total_harga;
    $new->status = 1;
    $new->save();
    $id = $new->id;
    Session::forget('cart');
    return redirect()->route('order.status', $id);
}
```

how to inserting multiple products from the shopping cart into the database as individual rows?

Thanks for the answer :)

Comment: Create ManyToMany relationship between product and order.

Comment: @tofa-maulana-irvan You need to add item insertion with in foreach

Comment: You need to create 2 tables; one for orders and one for orders products. Ordersproducts table will come in foreach that will contain all your item details

Comment: And main order table will contain only order id, total price, user id

Comment: @AmitGupta can you give me an example code?

Comment: @tofa-maulana-irvan Ok I will answer shortly with example that will help you

Comment: @AmitGupta thanks :)

Comment: @tofa-maulana-irvan Check my answer where I have made 2 tables; one for storing main information of order and other for storing all ordered products.

Comment: Example: If your Order Number is 1001 and ordered products id are 101, 102 and 103 then you will store order number in orders table but product id's in ordersproducts table with 3 rows.

Comment: Hope everything is clear. It will take some time to modify your code but once modified it will be easier to manage and more clear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To add multiple ordered items in database, you have to add 2 tables; **orders** and **ordersproducts**.

For adding all your `ordered items` after placing order, create one more table like `ordersproducts` where you will add your item details like product id, product name, description, unit price, quantity and the `orders` table must have main detail of the orders only like order number, user id, total products, total amount, order date. So `orders table` and `ordersproducts table` will look like below :

**Table: orders**

```
id int(10) UN AI PK
user_id int(11) 
payment varchar(255) 
courier varchar(255) 
note text 
total_quantity int(11) 
total_amount int(11) 
status int(11)
```

**Table: ordersproducts**

```
id int(10) UN AI PK
order_id int(11) 
product_id int(11) 
item_name text 
quantity int(11) 
price int(11)
```

**OrderController.php**

```
public function NewOrder(Request $request)
{
$this->validate($request, [
    'payment' => 'required',
    'courier' => 'required',
]);
$cart = Session::get('cart');
$total = 0;
foreach ($cart as $data) {
    $total_harga = $data['harga'] * $data['qty'];
    $qty = $data['qty'];
}
$quantity = $qty + 0;

$new = new Orders();
$new->user_id = Auth::user()->id;
$new->payment = $request['payment'];
$new->courier = $request['courier'];
$new->note = $request['note'];
$new->total_quantity = $quantity;
$new->total_amount = $total_harga;
$new->status = 1;
$new->save();

$order_id = DB::getPdo()->lastInsertId();

foreach ($cart as $data) {
    $total_harga = $data['harga'] * $data['qty'];
    $qty = $data['qty'];
    $OrderPro = new Ordersproducts;
    $OrderPro->order_id = $order_id;
    $OrderPro->product_id = $data['product_id'];
    $OrderPro->product_name = $data['product_name'];
    $OrderPro->product_price = $data['product_price'];
    $OrderPro->product_quantity = $data['product_quantity'];
    $OrderPro->save();
}

Session::forget('cart');
return redirect()->route('order.status', $id);
}
```

Please make changes in the above code as per your requirement. I have just given you a hint so that you can make 2 tables one for storing main details of order and one for complete product ordered details that you want.